# How to Resubmit an app after rejection on Play Store?

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload my first app on the Google Play Store but it got rejected due to the app's title included other apps or brands: "Rolling ball". After I corrected it And reuploaded a new apk with a higher version I still see the rejection message. It's been an hour and still nothing.

Comment: Add the reason of the rejection and changes you did to address it, also explain your resumit process. Probably is gonna take a a day or two.

Comment: Its going to take way longer than an hour, according to google 7 days max, the longest I  have waited for an app to be published was 3 days so be patient

Answer (score 0):

First point out the cause of rejection.
Then correct it and resubmit your apk with higher version code.

If it is okay then Google will publish your app.
So don't worry  if you are confirm about you solved the cause of rejection.
Just wait and it can take up to 7 days.
So just wait.